# Ubuntu 16.04.1 crashes after update

Tags: 16.04, updates, login, multiple-monitors, crash

Today I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 and immediately installed system updates.
After a restart, at the first login, the system crashes, showing me just a blue screen.

Here you can see a video, where at second 00.01, I pressed enter, after entering a correct password. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lk3u5IYBuO0

I tried the process a second time, just re-installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 and immediately updating it. Even in this case, after restart and login, the system crashed.

It feels like this can be an issue related to graphic configuration. Indeed after "login", I can see a second login UI, visible only for some milliseconds, after each keystroke.

This issue is a showstopper. As you can imagine, I won't feel safe anymore when updating Ubuntu.

How can I solve this problem and update without risks?

Details: I' working on a Toshiba Tecra S11, with one external monitor. 
So I have a configuration with one monitor 1600x900 (built-in set as secondary) and one 1920x1080 (LG external, set as primary)

Comment: I do have exactly the same problem with ubuntu 16.04 just installed, no applications or any other software. After OS updates, the system crashes exactly as it is reported in this post, I get the same blue screen. I could only reinstall ubuntu. If the system is updated, it crashes again.

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors?